# como enviar datos de un componente a un servidor en angula 6

Tags: angular

Hola amigos tengo una duda es posible enviar datos a servicio desde un componente y luego desde el servicio enviarlos a otro componente. en este código tengo errores pero en si lo que quisiera es pasar el array datos que esta en el primer componente al servicio y luego que el servicio me lo envié al componente 2, y de ante mano gracias por la ayuda

componente 1`<p>hola<p>`

`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import * as $ from 'jquery'; import {DatoscompraService} from './../datoscompra.service'
@Component({ 
 selector: 'app-carteras',
 templateUrl: './carteras.component.html', 
 styleUrls: ['./carteras.component.css'] }) 
 export class CarterasComponent implements OnInit { 
 datos:any = [ 
{
 producto:'Cartera 1',
 cantidad: 3,
 precio:200
 }, 
{
 producto:'Cartera 2',
 cantidad: 1
, precio:500
 },
 ];
constructor(private servicio:DatoscompraService) { }
ngOnInit() { }
public enviar(){ 
return this.datos; 
}
}`

servicio

`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class DatoscompraService {
datoss:any[] = [];
constructor() { }
public enviarPara(){
}
}`

componente 2

`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import * as $ from 'jquery'; import {DatoscompraService} from './../datoscompra.service'
@Component({
 selector: 'app-cabecera',
 templateUrl: './cabecera.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./cabecera.component.css'] }) 
export class CabeceraComponent implements OnInit {
datos:any[] = [];
constructor(private servicio:DatoscompraService){ this.datos = servicio.enviarPara(); }
ngOnInit() { }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para efectuar esto simplemente deberías mover el array al servicio, permitiendo que el objeto público e inyectarlo para todo el módulo.

Quedando tú código de la siguiente manera:
**Componente1:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { DatoscompraService } from './../datoscompra.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-carteras',
  templateUrl: './carteras.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carteras.component.css']
})
export class CarterasComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public servicio: DatoscompraService) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
  public enviar() {
    return this.servicio.datos;
  }
}
```

**Componente 2**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import * as $ from 'jquery'; 
import { DatoscompraService } from './../datoscompra.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cabecera',
  templateUrl: './cabecera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cabecera.component.css']
})
export class CabeceraComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public servicio: DatoscompraService) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**Servicio**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class DatoscompraService {
  datos: any[] = [];
  constructor() { }
  public enviarPara() {
  }
}
```

Para acceder al array de datos desde el template solamente tendras que indicar `servicio.datos`

Si inyectas este servicio en el módulo principal será compartido por toda la app el array ya que angular sigue el patrón singleton en los servicios manteniendo una única instancia del servicio según donde se haya inyectado.